# How to debug Java HTTPS cert validation

Tags: java, ssl

I have a third-party Java Application. It tries to download files via HTTPS. Sadly in my company network, HTTPS is intercepted and certs are replaced with non-rooted custom ones.

Now while I have our non-rooted CAs in `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` (double-checked) it still fails to download with:

```
java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz] to /tmp/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Is there any way to debug what JAVA is trying to do internally with cert validation?
Things like:

- Which CAs it's loading
- What steps it takes for validation
- Why validation is failing (in detail)

Bonus points if I don't need to use reflection or something obscure ;)

Comment: Normally, `cacerts` is located in `JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`. Are you sure the `cacerts` file you have is the one used when you run Java?

Answer (score 3):

I would try using the dynamic debug utility. There is an option to turn on SSL debugging which ought to help you.

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug)

> JSSE provides dynamic debug tracing support. This is similar to the
>   support used for debugging access control failures in the Java SE
>   platform. The generic Java dynamic debug tracing support is accessed
>   with the java.security.debug system property, whereas the
>   JSSE-specific dynamic debug tracing support is accessed with the
>   javax.net.debug system property. Current options are:
>
> ```
> all: Turn on all debugging
> ssl: Turn on SSL debugging
> ```
>
> The following can be used with the ssl option:
>
> ```
> record: Enable per-record tracing
> handshake: Print each handshake message
> keygen: Print key generation data
> session: Print session activity
> defaultctx: Print default SSL initialization
> sslctx: Print SSLContext tracing
> sessioncache: Print session cache tracing
> keymanager: Print key manager tracing
> trustmanager: Print trust manager tracing
> ```

I think this ought to help you.

Comment: This does not log anything about certificate validation

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly. If you really need to debug it, check out Vinnie's answer instead.

The error message is pretty specific and I think you've already given the answer as to why it fails - your traffic is intercepted and the certificates are replaced "in flight". Your problem probably is that your JVM isn't loading `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` and is not able to trust the intercepted certificate chain. To specify that specific `cacerts` file, add `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` as a VM option, like so

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -jar thirdPartyApplication.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the default `SUN` provider, start the JVM with the following argument:

```
-Djava.security.debug=certpath
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/troubleshooting-security.html

> Turns on debugging for the PKIX `CertPathValidator` and `CertPathBuilder` implementations. Use the `ocsp` option with the `certpath` option for OCSP protocol tracing. A hexadecimal dump of the OCSP request and response bytes is displayed.

Other providers may also use this switch.